# vb.net dropdownlist datasource

Tags: .net, vb.net

have 3 dropdown list one has pre set values and my post back works 
the other 2 has the data from the db when i try using post back on them i don't get anything in my grid view.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlname" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"     DataTextField="Venue_Name" DataValueField="Venue_Name" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True"> <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="All" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>     </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FloorPlanOfficeConnectionString3 %>" 

 SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Venue Name] AS Venue_Name FROM [vMelvilleFloorPlan_Complete]">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

in my .vb code

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Venue_Name", ddlname.SelectedValue)
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@All_Venue_Name", IIf(ddlname.SelectedValue = "All", 1, 0))
```

that's not populating my grid view

Comment: Is that your solution, or an extension to the above? If it's a solution then add it as an answer for others to benefit from and you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: thats an extension to above it cut out part of my code

Answer (score 0):

To add to jmoreno's answer, try this

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Venue_Name", ddlname.SelectedItem.Value)
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@All_Venue_Name", IIf(ddlname.SelectedItem.Value = "All", 1, 0))
```